# Obtener filas que tengan una fecha mayor o menor a una determinada

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, select, sql-server-ce

tengo una aplicación en la cuál quiero seleccionar desde 2 timePickers la fecha menor y mayor, para luego hacer un select * from utilizando las fechas como condiciones.

Tengo esto:

```
var select = "SELECT * from inventario where ifechaCompra > "+diarioFecha1.Text+" and ifechaCompra < "+diarioFecha2.Text+"";
            SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexionDB"].ConnectionString);
            var dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(select, con);
            var commandBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            tablaInventario.ReadOnly = true;
            tablaInventario.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Lo extraño es que si en el lugar de la segunda fecha yo quito el `diarioFecha.Text` y le introduzco una así: `'01/01/2014'` sí  funciona.

No me da ningún error, simplemente al actualizarme el dgv me lo deja vacío.

PD: *sé que debería usar parámetros pero cuando tengo que llenar una dgv no sé como hacerlo, solo sé para insertar.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que no te dé un error y simplemente no te traiga datos, puede deberse a que con los filtros indicados no exista información, o que tal como has formateado los valores el motor "confunda" días por mes. Te sugiero:

1. En primer lugar no suele ser una buena idea usar este formato
   '01/01/2014' para indicar una fecha, ¿cómo hace el motor para
   identificar el día del mes? es preferible usar el formato ISO largo
   `yyyymmdd` es decir `20140101`. Tal vez te convenga armar una función "normalizadora" que reciba el valor de diarioFecha1.Text y formatee la fecha al formato iso, a menos que `diarioFecha1` ya te ofrezca alguna forma de retornar la fecha con dicho formato.
2. El otro tema es que en tu consulta debes separar con comillas los
   parámetros de fecha de la siguiente forma:

   ```
   var select = "SELECT * from inventario where ifechaCompra > '"+diarioFecha1.Text+"' and ifechaCompra < '"+diarioFecha2.Text+"'";
   ```
3. Pero mucho mejor es procesar los parámetros para evitar problemas de inyección de código, así:

   ```
   var select = "SELECT * from inventario where ifechaCompra > @FechaDesde and  ifechaCompra < @FechaHasta";
   SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexionDB"].ConnectionString);

   dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaDesde",diarioFecha1.Text);
   dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaHasta",diarioFecha2.Text);

   var dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(select, con);
   ```
4. Por último, y esto es opinable, en mi experiencia (en Argentina al menos) los límites son mas claros si son inclusivos, es decir `>=` o `<=`, generalmente un usuario si quiere ver a partir del 01/01/2014, espera ver datos de ese día también. Pero eso dependerá de la cultura de cada país u organización.
5. Y como última recomendación, aplicable a cualquier consulta: nunca usar un `select *`, siempre indicar los campos que específicamente vamos a usar, esto muchas veces tiene un impacto muy alto en el tráfico de red.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda y por los consejos, me solucionaste lo que pedía y más, se necesita mas gente como vos, gracias  en serio :')